# My code doesn't want to execute on a program called Xenobot / XenoSuite, my if then function doesn't work

Tags: lua

So I've just started learning Lua coding, and I've followed somebodies code online on youtube and I've done word for word to exactly what he has done. When I execute the code it doesn't work. Can somebody please explain to me what it is and rewrite whatever is wrong. Thanks. I've ran the code a few times with everything you can see below. The line that doesn't work is the one that says if (labelName == "Venore") then. Everything else does. I've ran them all individually and the moment I type that one line in the code just doesn't want to be executed and it doesn't run in the script. I don't know if I wrote something wrong but this is exactly what the code looks like.

What I would like to do is create an automated script for the game where if a label in the "Walker", which is inside the game, you can create labels, I want these to be checkpoints the script checks. When the label has been detected it will execute the code so for example if I type in the "Walker" section, "Venore" it will execute the section where it has detected "Venore".

This code is for a game called tibia, the code is for a program called Xenobot / Xenosuite. I'm also using notepad++ to make this code. I've followed this youtube video to try and understand why my code doesn't work. I've followed all the instructions on there my code looks exactly like it does on that video however the program doesn't want to be executed. Here is a link to the youtube video I used http://youtube.com/watch?v=le8uT7Dg7zg, I hope all this information helps.

```
----- Mana Potions -----
local ManaMin = 50 --- How many mana potions until you leave the hunt
local ManaMax = 300 --- How many mana poitions you begin with
local ManaID = 237 --- ID Strong Health Potion
local ManaCost = 100 --- Price of Strong Mana Potion

----- Health Potions -----
local HealthMin = 0 --- How many health potions until you leave the hunt
local HealthMax = 0 --- How many mana poitions you begin with
local HealthID = 236 --- ID Strong Mana Potion
local HealthCost = 100 --- Price of Strong Health Potion

----- Other Options -----
local MainBp = 10234
local ItemBp = 2867
local GoldBp = 2671
local StackBp = 5949
local SuppliesBp = 2868
local RingBp = 10234
local MinCap = 100

local UsingSoftBoots = true
local HideEquipment = true

---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------



Targeting.Start()
Looter.Start()

registerEventListener(WALKER_SELECTLABEL, "onWalkerSelectLabel")

local info = [[]]
    wait(5000)
    
    print([[
    --<Hello and welcome to my code>--]])
    wait(3000)
    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function onWalkerSelectLabel(labelName)
if (labelName == "Venore") then
    setWalkerEnabled(false)
        delayWalker(5000)
            Self.Say("Hi")
            sleep(math.random(700, 1400))
            Self.SayToNpc("Venore")
            sleep(math.random(300, 1000))
            Self.SayToNpc("Yes")
        setWalkerEnabled(true)

end
```

If you see in the code the part "if (labelName == "Venore") then", where it says Venore, that is a City in the game so when the character goes to the boat, it will communicate with the npc and go to Venore. When it comes to moving the character around this is all already with the bot and in the first image where you saw all the labels. The Node's are the locations the bot tells the character to move.

Can't post images yet sorry would have been a lot easier if I could. I hope all this helps if not I can provide more information.

Comment: what is the value of label? print it!

Answer (score 0):

So basically I found out what the problem was, all I had to do was add "end" to the script and it works now.